# ASP.NET System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException : org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement Error

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, soap, wsdl, apache-axis

I was able to successfully add a web reference in Visual studio.(wsdl file). And it automatically did create the proxy class for me with all the methods. But when I try to invoke a web service method, I get the following exception

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException : org.apache.axis2.databinding.ADBException: Unexpected subelement request
```

I am not sure, what the problem here is. Is it something to do with the wsdl file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wsdl file was not in correct format. I had to make sure that the wsdl was in correct format, by saving the online files locally using the proper extension.